# Wrong default include directories for clang cross-compile?

Tags: compiling, clang

My build machine is xenial x86_64. I am cross-compiling for arm-linux-gnueabihf. I have installed g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf.

When building with `clang++ --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`, I get the error "`/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/string:38:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found`". But why is it reading `/usr/include/c++/5/string`?

Using the command suggested in ["Dump include paths from g++"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946295/431033)
, I check the include paths for `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`:

```
$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf-cross/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf-cross --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf-cross --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libgcj --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -D_GNU_SOURCE - -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -mtls-dialect=gnu -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Then I check the include paths for `clang++-3.8 --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang++-3.8 --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/nullclang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: arm--linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m32
 "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple armv6kz--linux-gnueabihf -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu arm1176jzf-s -target-feature +strict-align -target-abi aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi hard -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/arm--linux-gnueabihf/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/leo/ws/odroid_ws -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 157 -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 3.8.0 based upon LLVM 3.8.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/5.4.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/arm--linux-gnueabihf/c++/5.4.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

I notice (after using readlink to remove the mess of ../.. from the paths):

**`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`** uses **/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5**, and does not use /usr/include/c++/5.

**`clang++ --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`** uses **/usr/include/c++/5**, and does not use /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.

Is clang wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what is wrong with clang and/or my system configuration , but I used these flags as a workaround:

`-nostdinc++ -cxx-isystem /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5 -cxx-isystem /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5/arm-linux-gnueabihf`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys-root` in this case. Clang, as of 6.0 (unreleased ATM), seems to work around the numerous ways GNU libraries and tools (gcc, glibc, and libstdc++ in particular) are laid out on Linux distros. You may still have some issues, which is where using

```
clang -v ...
```

as well as

```
strace -e 'trace=!write' clang ...
```

to see the directories Clang is searching for will help. I've found a hacky solution on Fedora. I am currently doing:

(I'm using gcc 7 and clang here, and `<sysroot>=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys-root`)

1. Install cross compilation prereqs (varies by distro, but Fedora has a filesystem package which creates the `<sysroot>` folder). This also includes all binaries and development headers for your target platform. Unfortunately, there aren't great out of the box solutions for this on many platforms. For instance, Fedora lacks `libstdc++` for aarch64, but IIRC Debian and Ubuntu have this.
2. Create a sysroot for the platform

   ```
   mkdir -p <sysroot>/lib/gcc
   ln -s <sysroot>/include <sysroot>/usr/include # Another Clang quirk, it seems
   ```
3. Copy GCC binaries and libstdc++ headers. This is some what frustrating, as the way Clang looks for GCC installations is by searching common paths (*e.g.*, `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu`) and going up X number of directories to find associated headers. This means that unless you can create hard links from your gcc binaries to your new sys-root, that you will need to copy the binaries and (some) headers. This is what I had to do in order to get this to work (it may be different for you):

   ```
   cp -r /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ <sysroot>/lib/gcc
   # Fedora installs C++ headers here, but we will copy them into sys-root
   # Copy all of your other headers in the same manner
   cp -r /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++ <sysroot>/include
   ```
4. Add the `--sysroot=` flag to clang

   ```
   clang --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=<sysroot> ...
   ```

Most of the logic in Clang that deals with searching for these directories seems to be within these files (they may not exist on older versions of Clang):

[lib/Driver/Toolchains/Gnu.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_60/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Gnu.cpp)

[lib/Driver/Toolchains/Linux.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_60/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Linux.cpp)

Comment: Thanks, just saw this answer. I don't quite see why your multi-step process of copying binaries and headers is needed, compared to my workaround of `-nostdinc++ -cxx-isystem=...`. Are you just describing a different situation on another distribution?

Comment: I try to use `--sysroot` as opposed to `-nostdinc++` because I am not sure if the latter will automatically choose the correct C++ binary. I did say that my work around was a hack, so I can't defend my approach much beyond this.